# GroovyDoc in Gradle not working

Tags: gradle, groovydoc

I am trying to generate groovydocs in gradle script using command `gradle groovydoc`. I can see the command executed successfully as below:

```
Dynamic properties are deprecated: http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:groovydoc UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

But I don't see any API generated in the file system. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you provide, it's impossible to say. We'd have to see the build scripts, output of `gradle -v`, etc. The first line of output indicates that you may have misspelled a configuration property in the build script. Recent versions of Gradle will print the property in question. If you get the `UP-TO-DATE` even for `gradle clean groovydoc`, it's a clear sign that something isn't configured correctly.

Comment: Yes. Even if it prints the UP-TO-DATE doesn't mean it has generated the groovydocs. I figured out the issue which is causing grrovydoc not to generate and fixed that. Any how Thanks Peter.